# Add a delay in dropdown menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, delay

Please help, need to add delay on css menu mouse out. Tried different ways but no success. Is it possible to add some javascript code to existing menu?

Please check the jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/mZLFz/

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li class="abt"><a href="#" title="">About Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Our style</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Our mission</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="col"><a href="#">Collection</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="col-a"><a href="#">2013</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-b"><a href="#">2014</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="buy"><a href="#">Good to know</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="buy-a"><a href="#">Men</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="buy-b"><a href="#">Women</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
                <li class="buy-c"><a href="#">Kids</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                </ul>                   
            </li>
        </ul>           
    </li>
```

```
#nav{
height:40px;
overflow:hidden;
list-style:none;
}
        #nav ul {list-style:none;}
        #nav ul li {text-decoration: none;float:left;}
        #nav ul li a {
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-size:14px;
        color:#bcbec0;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding:0 20px 3px 20px;
        }
        #nav ul li:hover > a{border-bottom: 2px solid #afb0bd;color:#383a49;}
/* 1 LEVEL DROP-DOWN MENU */
#nav ul li.abt ul {margin-left:-30px;}              
#nav ul li.col ul {margin-left:-100px;}
#nav ul li.buy ul { margin-left: -213px;}
#nav ul li.buy ul li {margin-left: 30px;}
#nav ul li ul { display:none;}
#nav ul li:hover > ul {width:100%;display:block; position:absolute; top:48px;background:#e7e8e9;}
#nav ul li:hover > ul li{ float:left;padding:10px 0 5px 0;list-style:none;}
#nav ul li:hover > ul li a {}
#nav ul li:hover > ul li a:hover {}

/* 2 LEVEL DROP-DOWN MENU */
#nav ul li ul li.col-a ul { margin-left:-50px;top:35px;}
#nav ul li ul li.col-b ul { margin-left:-100px;top:35px;}
#nav ul li ul li.buy-a ul { margin-left:-30px;top:35px;}
#nav ul li ul li.buy-b ul { margin-left:-160px;top:35px;}
#nav ul li ul li.buy-c ul { margin-left:-30px;top:35px;}
#nav ul li > ul li ul { display:none; }
#nav ul li > ul li:hover > ul {width:980px; display:block; position:absolute;background:#f1f1f2;}
#nav ul li > ul li:hover ul li {float:left;padding-top:10px; list-style:none;  }
#nav ul li > ul li:hover ul li a {}
#nav ul li > ul li:hover ul li a:hover { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change some `:hover` to `.hover` and add some jQuery like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7SuuU/)?

```
    $('li').hover(
        function(){
             var x = this; 
             setTimeout(
                 function(){
                      $(x).addClass('hover')
                 }, 800
             )
        },
        function(){
              $(this).removeClass('hover')
        }
    )
```

Comment: thank you, works like a charm, but how to add delay when you move the mouse out the link?